# Restart containers within ECS when a certain container is deployed

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I have a project that runs multiple GO services using ECS. For example, I have 3 containers, A, B, C, and then container D holds config and stuff for the other containers. Is there a way that when container D is updated or restarted I can then restart the other containers within ECS so they can use the new data from container D?

I was thinking of having a pub/sub type thing and telling the other containers a new version had been released but I was thinking there must be an easier way that doesn't involve any extra code.

I'd also like to do this for my local docker-compose stack if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I found you can add container dependencies within the task definition JSON.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerDependency.html

This allows you to add dependencies for the different containers running.

For example:

```
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "image": "application_image",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 9080,
          "hostPort": 9080,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "dependsOn": [
        {
          "containerName": "container-a",
          "condition": "HEALTHY"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

In ECS you can define all containers A,B,C and D within the same task if there are dependencies between them (having all of them in your task definition).
If one container is going down within the task - all task containers are stopped (a new task is started instead). The deployment is in the task level - so deploying a new task will replace all the containers within it.

If you want more flexibility (having separate deployment for A,B,C) you can create 3 different tasks, each one has two containers - one of A/B/C and D (as a sidecar):

- Task_A - running both containers A & D.
- Task_B - running both containers B & D.
- Task_C - running both containers C & D.

In `docker-compose` you can run `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit` so when one container is down everything goes down as well.

Comment: Just to add one thing: make sure to mark container D as essential in the task definition.